# How to specify which service to access the Internet through

Tags: macos, routing

- I have WiFi and a Thunderbolt Ethernet. WiFi is above Ethernet in Network Prefs "service order."
- The WiFi AP's WAN is a cable modem.
- The Ethernet switch is only for a local LAN and doesn't have a WAN.

  1. I connect to WiFi and can ping 4.2.2.1
  2. I then also connect the ethernet cable, and my pings timeout – I assume they're being routed through Ethernet

How can I tell my Mac to route everything but `192.168.0.*` through `192.168.2.1`? Preferably in a way that only applies to this scenario (eg "prioritize WiFi over Ethernet"), so that when I travel and connect to a different WiFi that's on `192.168.0.1`, I can still access the Internet.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this question was answered here:
https://serverfault.com/a/402215

The trick was to clear the "Router:" field on the LAN interface.

> 1. Go to System Preferences -> Network
> 2. Select your Ethernet device, make sure "Configure IPv4" is set to "Manually", that your subnet mask is set to 255.255.255.0, and that the router box is empty.
>
> Once this is done, netstat -rn should still show the routes for both of the subnets, but only a "link#4" route in place of the default route through 192.168.2.1.